# Does "something is denied to me" basically equals "something is denied me" in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, grammaticality-in-context, syntax

> “I wish I could say anything to comfort you,” replied Elizabeth, “but
>   it is wholly out of my power. You must feel it, and **the usual
>   satisfaction of preaching patience to a sufferer is denied me**,
>   because you have always so much.”
>
> from *Pride and Prejudice*

I understand that :

1. [deny somebody something],  as in :    They were denied access.

or

2. [deny something to somebody] , as in :  Access was denied **to** them.

But in some archaic usage as in the above mentioned, **there is no "to"**; so can I conclude that :

**[something be denied to somebody] = [something be denied somebody]  ?**

**or,**

should I conclude that it's another usage of "deny":

**{ something be denied somebody} = { somebody can't have something }?**

Could someone help please, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't have thought of it as particularly archaic, but, yes, Elizabeth means that the satisfaction is denied *to* her.

Comment: So it's a formal speech?  and do common English people still speak this way? like: All dairy products are denied me since I am lactose intolerant.  The confusion for me is why "to" is missed here.  People say "it is given to me", not "it is given me“， right?

Comment: I didn't say it was formal, though Jane Austen's characters do speak a rather formal English. It is still possible to say _it is denied me_ and _it is given me_ (see https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/147050/which-was-given-me-vs-which-was-given-to-me and try Googling _it is given me_.

Comment: I see now. thank you so much!  I was mislead/influenced by another post saying this usage is formal and dated. https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/28859/why-isnt-there-by-in-this-passive-voice/28861#28861